# Error: The process '/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.4/x64/bin/bundle' failed with exit code 16 in a Github Actions Setup Ruby Job

Tags: ruby, github-actions, jekyll, github-pages

I'm facing an issue with running a build job through Github Actions because Error: `The process '/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.4/x64/bin/bundle' failed with exit code 16` during the Setup Ruby job.

My ruby version is 3.2.:

```
❯ ruby -v
ruby 3.2.2 (2023-03-30 revision e51014f9c0) [arm64-darwin22]
```

Here's `jekyll.yml`:

```yaml
# Sample workflow for building and deploying a Jekyll site to GitHub Pages
name: Deploy Jekyll site to Pages

on:
  # Runs on pushes targeting the default branch
  push:
    branches: ["main"]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

# Sets permissions of the GITHUB_TOKEN to allow deployment to GitHub Pages
permissions:
  contents: read
  pages: write
  id-token: write

# Allow only one concurrent deployment, skipping runs queued between the run in-progress and latest queued.
# However, do NOT cancel in-progress runs as we want to allow these production deployments to complete.
concurrency:
  group: "pages"
  cancel-in-progress: false

jobs:
  # Build job
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Setup Ruby
        uses: ruby/setup-ruby@55283cc23133118229fd3f97f9336ee23a179fcf # v1.146.0
        with:
          ruby-version: "3.2.2"
          bundler-cache: true # runs 'bundle install' and caches installed gems automatically
          cache-version: 0 # Increment this number if you need to re-download cached gems
      - name: Build with Jekyll
        # Outputs to the './_site' directory by default
        run: bundle exec jekyll build --baseurl "${{ steps.pages.outputs.base_path }}"
        env:
          JEKYLL_ENV: production
      - name: Upload artifact
        # Automatically uploads an artifact from the './_site' directory by default
        uses: actions/upload-pages-artifact@v1

  # Deployment job
  deploy:
    environment:
      name: github-pages
      url: ${{ steps.deployment.outputs.page_url }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    steps:
      - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
        id: deployment
        uses: actions/deploy-pages@v2
```

### Environment

```
Bundler       2.4.15
  Platforms   ruby, arm64-darwin-22
Ruby          3.2.2p53 (2023-03-30 revision e51014f9c05aa65cbf203442d37fef7c12390015) [arm64-darwin-22]
  Full Path   /Users/kamilszafraniak/.rubies/ruby-3.2.2/bin/ruby
  Config Dir  /Users/kamilszafraniak/.rubies/ruby-3.2.2/etc
RubyGems      3.4.15
  Gem Home    /Users/kamilszafraniak/.gem/ruby/3.2.2
  Gem Path    /Users/kamilszafraniak/.gem/ruby/3.2.2:/Users/kamilszafraniak/.rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0
  User Home   /Users/kamilszafraniak
  User Path   /Users/kamilszafraniak/.gem/ruby/3.2.0
  Bin Dir     /Users/kamilszafraniak/.gem/ruby/3.2.2/bin
Tools         
  Git         2.39.2 (Apple Git-143)
  RVM         not installed
  rbenv       rbenv 1.2.0
  chruby      0.3.9
```

### Bundler Build Metadata

```
Built At          2023-06-29
Git SHA           702f922bf2
Released Version  true
```

### Gemfile.lock

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    activesupport (7.0.6)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 1.6, < 2)
      minitest (>= 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 2.0)
    addressable (2.8.4)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 6.0)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.11.1)
    colorator (1.1.0)
    commonmarker (0.23.9)
    concurrent-ruby (1.2.2)
    dnsruby (1.70.0)
      simpleidn (~> 0.2.1)
    em-websocket (0.5.3)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.9)
      http_parser.rb (~> 0)
    ethon (0.16.0)
      ffi (>= 1.15.0)
    eventmachine (1.2.7)
    execjs (2.8.1)
    faraday (2.7.9)
      faraday-net_http (>= 2.0, < 3.1)
      ruby2_keywords (>= 0.0.4)
    faraday-net_http (3.0.2)
    ffi (1.15.5)
    forwardable-extended (2.6.0)
    gemoji (3.0.1)
    github-pages (228)
      github-pages-health-check (= 1.17.9)
      jekyll (= 3.9.3)
      jekyll-avatar (= 0.7.0)
      jekyll-coffeescript (= 1.1.1)
      jekyll-commonmark-ghpages (= 0.4.0)
      jekyll-default-layout (= 0.1.4)
      jekyll-feed (= 0.15.1)
      jekyll-gist (= 1.5.0)
      jekyll-github-metadata (= 2.13.0)
      jekyll-include-cache (= 0.2.1)
      jekyll-mentions (= 1.6.0)
      jekyll-optional-front-matter (= 0.3.2)
      jekyll-paginate (= 1.1.0)
      jekyll-readme-index (= 0.3.0)
      jekyll-redirect-from (= 0.16.0)
      jekyll-relative-links (= 0.6.1)
      jekyll-remote-theme (= 0.4.3)
      jekyll-sass-converter (= 1.5.2)
      jekyll-seo-tag (= 2.8.0)
      jekyll-sitemap (= 1.4.0)
      jekyll-swiss (= 1.0.0)
      jekyll-theme-architect (= 0.2.0)
      jekyll-theme-cayman (= 0.2.0)
      jekyll-theme-dinky (= 0.2.0)
      jekyll-theme-hacker (= 0.2.0)
      jekyll-theme-leap-day (= 0.2.0)
      jekyll-theme-merlot (= 0.2.0)
      jekyll-theme-midnight (= 0.2.0)
      jekyll-theme-minimal (= 0.2.0)
      jekyll-theme-modernist (= 0.2.0)
      jekyll-theme-primer (= 0.6.0)
      jekyll-theme-slate (= 0.2.0)
      jekyll-theme-tactile (= 0.2.0)
      jekyll-theme-time-machine (= 0.2.0)
      jekyll-titles-from-headings (= 0.5.3)
      jemoji (= 0.12.0)
      kramdown (= 2.3.2)
      kramdown-parser-gfm (= 1.1.0)
      liquid (= 4.0.4)
      mercenary (~> 0.3)
      minima (= 2.5.1)
      nokogiri (>= 1.13.6, < 2.0)
      rouge (= 3.26.0)
      terminal-table (~> 1.4)
    github-pages-health-check (1.17.9)
      addressable (~> 2.3)
      dnsruby (~> 1.60)
      octokit (~> 4.0)
      public_suffix (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      typhoeus (~> 1.3)
    html-pipeline (2.14.3)
      activesupport (>= 2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4)
    http_parser.rb (0.8.0)
    i18n (1.14.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    jekyll (3.9.3)
      addressable (~> 2.4)
      colorator (~> 1.0)
      em-websocket (~> 0.5)
      i18n (>= 0.7, < 2)
      jekyll-sass-converter (~> 1.0)
      jekyll-watch (~> 2.0)
      kramdown (>= 1.17, < 3)
      liquid (~> 4.0)
      mercenary (~> 0.3.3)
      pathutil (~> 0.9)
      rouge (>= 1.7, < 4)
      safe_yaml (~> 1.0)
    jekyll-avatar (0.7.0)
      jekyll (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
    jekyll-coffeescript (1.1.1)
      coffee-script (~> 2.2)
      coffee-script-source (~> 1.11.1)
    jekyll-commonmark (1.4.0)
      commonmarker (~> 0.22)
    jekyll-commonmark-ghpages (0.4.0)
      commonmarker (~> 0.23.7)
      jekyll (~> 3.9.0)
      jekyll-commonmark (~> 1.4.0)
      rouge (>= 2.0, < 5.0)
    jekyll-data (1.1.1)
      jekyll (>= 3.3, < 5.0.0)
    jekyll-default-layout (0.1.4)
      jekyll (~> 3.0)
    jekyll-feed (0.15.1)
      jekyll (>= 3.7, < 5.0)
    jekyll-gist (1.5.0)
      octokit (~> 4.2)
    jekyll-github-metadata (2.13.0)
      jekyll (>= 3.4, < 5.0)
      octokit (~> 4.0, != 4.4.0)
    jekyll-include-cache (0.2.1)
      jekyll (>= 3.7, < 5.0)
    jekyll-mentions (1.6.0)
      html-pipeline (~> 2.3)
      jekyll (>= 3.7, < 5.0)
    jekyll-optional-front-matter (0.3.2)
      jekyll (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
    jekyll-paginate (1.1.0)
    jekyll-readme-index (0.3.0)
      jekyll (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
    jekyll-redirect-from (0.16.0)
      jekyll (>= 3.3, < 5.0)
    jekyll-relative-links (0.6.1)
      jekyll (>= 3.3, < 5.0)
    jekyll-remote-theme (0.4.3)
      addressable (~> 2.0)
      jekyll (>= 3.5, < 5.0)
      jekyll-sass-converter (>= 1.0, <= 3.0.0, != 2.0.0)
      rubyzip (>= 1.3.0, < 3.0)
    jekyll-sass-converter (1.5.2)
      sass (~> 3.4)
    jekyll-seo-tag (2.8.0)
      jekyll (>= 3.8, < 5.0)
    jekyll-sitemap (1.4.0)
      jekyll (>= 3.7, < 5.0)
    jekyll-swiss (1.0.0)
    jekyll-theme-architect (0.2.0)
      jekyll (> 3.5, < 5.0)
      jekyll-seo-tag (~> 2.0)
    jekyll-theme-cayman (0.2.0)
      jekyll (> 3.5, < 5.0)
      jekyll-seo-tag (~> 2.0)
    jekyll-theme-dinky (0.2.0)
      jekyll (> 3.5, < 5.0)
      jekyll-seo-tag (~> 2.0)
    jekyll-theme-hacker (0.2.0)
      jekyll (> 3.5, < 5.0)
      jekyll-seo-tag (~> 2.0)
    jekyll-theme-leap-day (0.2.0)
      jekyll (> 3.5, < 5.0)
      jekyll-seo-tag (~> 2.0)
    jekyll-theme-merlot (0.2.0)
      jekyll (> 3.5, < 5.0)
      jekyll-seo-tag (~> 2.0)
    jekyll-theme-midnight (0.2.0)
      jekyll (> 3.5, < 5.0)
      jekyll-seo-tag (~> 2.0)
    jekyll-theme-minimal (0.2.0)
      jekyll (> 3.5, < 5.0)
      jekyll-seo-tag (~> 2.0)
    jekyll-theme-modernist (0.2.0)
      jekyll (> 3.5, < 5.0)
      jekyll-seo-tag (~> 2.0)
    jekyll-theme-primer (0.6.0)
      jekyll (> 3.5, < 5.0)
      jekyll-github-metadata (~> 2.9)
      jekyll-seo-tag (~> 2.0)
    jekyll-theme-slate (0.2.0)
      jekyll (> 3.5, < 5.0)
      jekyll-seo-tag (~> 2.0)
    jekyll-theme-tactile (0.2.0)
      jekyll (> 3.5, < 5.0)
      jekyll-seo-tag (~> 2.0)
    jekyll-theme-time-machine (0.2.0)
      jekyll (> 3.5, < 5.0)
      jekyll-seo-tag (~> 2.0)
    jekyll-titles-from-headings (0.5.3)
      jekyll (>= 3.3, < 5.0)
    jekyll-watch (2.2.1)
      listen (~> 3.0)
    jemoji (0.12.0)
      gemoji (~> 3.0)
      html-pipeline (~> 2.2)
      jekyll (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
    kramdown (2.3.2)
      rexml
    kramdown-parser-gfm (1.1.0)
      kramdown (~> 2.0)
    liquid (4.0.4)
    listen (3.8.0)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.10, >= 0.10.3)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.10)
    mercenary (0.3.6)
    minima (2.5.1)
      jekyll (>= 3.5, < 5.0)
      jekyll-feed (~> 0.9)
      jekyll-seo-tag (~> 2.1)
    minitest (5.18.1)
    nokogiri (1.15.2-arm64-darwin)
      racc (~> 1.4)
    nokogiri (1.15.2-x86_64-linux)
      racc (~> 1.4)
    octokit (4.25.1)
      faraday (>= 1, < 3)
      sawyer (~> 0.9)
    pathutil (0.16.2)
      forwardable-extended (~> 2.6)
    public_suffix (4.0.7)
    racc (1.7.1)
    rb-fsevent (0.11.2)
    rb-inotify (0.10.1)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    rexml (3.2.5)
    rouge (3.26.0)
    ruby2_keywords (0.0.5)
    rubyzip (2.3.2)
    safe_yaml (1.0.5)
    sass (3.7.4)
      sass-listen (~> 4.0.0)
    sass-listen (4.0.0)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
    sawyer (0.9.2)
      addressable (>= 2.3.5)
      faraday (>= 0.17.3, < 3)
    simpleidn (0.2.1)
      unf (~> 0.1.4)
    terminal-table (1.8.0)
      unicode-display_width (~> 1.1, >= 1.1.1)
    typhoeus (1.4.0)
      ethon (>= 0.9.0)
    tzinfo (2.0.6)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    unf (0.1.4)
      unf_ext
    unf_ext (0.0.8.2)
    unicode-display_width (1.8.0)

PLATFORMS
  arm64-darwin-22
  x86_64-linux

DEPENDENCIES
  github-pages
  jekyll
  jekyll-data
  jekyll-feed
  jekyll-include-cache
  jekyll-seo-tag
  jekyll-sitemap

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 3.2.2p53

BUNDLED WITH
   2.4.15
```

Here are lines from the build job around the error:

```
Installing Bundler
> bundle install
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.4/x64/bin/bundle config --local path /home/runner/work/szfkamil.github.io/szfkamil.github.io/vendor/bundle
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.4/x64/bin/bundle config --local deployment true
Cache key: setup-ruby-bundler-cache-v6-ubuntu-22.04-x64-ruby-3.1.4-wd-/home/runner/work/szfkamil.github.io/szfkamil.github.io-with--without--Gemfile.lock-9636c100a31e3f118728b67f75140200b016e6cfdb25323d245ea06340c24623
##[debug]Resolved Keys:
##[debug]["setup-ruby-bundler-cache-v6-ubuntu-22.04-x64-ruby-3.1.4-wd-/home/runner/work/szfkamil.github.io/szfkamil.github.io-with--without--Gemfile.lock-9636c100a31e3f118728b67f75140200b016e6cfdb25323d245ea06340c24623","setup-ruby-bundler-cache-v6-ubuntu-22.04-x64-ruby-3.1.4-wd-/home/runner/work/szfkamil.github.io/szfkamil.github.io-with--without--Gemfile.lock-"]
##[debug]Checking zstd --quiet --version
##[debug]1.5.5
##[debug]zstd version: 1.5.5
##[debug]Resource Url: https://artifactcache.actions.githubusercontent.com/pShi4GArC0OyKHbxaD7TUGhhmgPFlZ2gDALucp68P2yHvAZaTf/_apis/artifactcache/cache?keys=setup-ruby-bundler-cache-v6-ubuntu-22.04-x64-ruby-3.1.4-wd-%2Fhome%2Frunner%2Fwork%2Fszfkamil.github.io%2Fszfkamil.github.io-with--without--Gemfile.lock-9636c100a31e3f118728b67f75140200b016e6cfdb25323d245ea06340c24623%2Csetup-ruby-bundler-cache-v6-ubuntu-22.04-x64-ruby-3.1.4-wd-%2Fhome%2Frunner%2Fwork%2Fszfkamil.github.io%2Fszfkamil.github.io-with--without--Gemfile.lock-&version=f3a190c975da8339aef2d723682c8fb06999ced0c1e8592447dabecbf40062e3
##[debug]Resource Url: https://artifactcache.actions.githubusercontent.com/pShi4GArC0OyKHbxaD7TUGhhmgPFlZ2gDALucp68P2yHvAZaTf/_apis/artifactcache/caches?key=setup-ruby-bundler-cache-v6-ubuntu-22.04-x64-ruby-3.1.4-wd-%2Fhome%2Frunner%2Fwork%2Fszfkamil.github.io%2Fszfkamil.github.io-with--without--Gemfile.lock-9636c100a31e3f118728b67f75140200b016e6cfdb25323d245ea06340c24623
##[debug]Failed to delete archive: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, unlink ''
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.4/x64/bin/bundle install --jobs 4
Your bundle only supports platforms ["arm64-darwin-22"] but your local platform
is x86_64-linux. Add the current platform to the lockfile with
`bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux` and try again.
Error: The process '/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.1.4/x64/bin/bundle' failed with exit code 16
##[debug]Node Action run completed with exit code 1
##[debug]Finishing: Setup Ruby
```

The expected behavior is a successful run of the build job for the site.

I would appreciate any assistance or guidance to help resolve this issue. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Run this command locally and commit & push

```
bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux
```

Your CI environment is Ubuntu.

```
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
```